# Application "AppName" is inventing the lower-case namespace "appname", causing the "AppName" namespace to become ambiguous

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

As I say, I've got an application which I'll refer to as "AppName" (note the upper case 'A' and 'N') which, for example, attempts to reference "My.Application.Info.ProductName".

Adding a breakpoint and putting a QuickWatch on that call shows the error:

```
        My.Application.Info.ProductName 'Application' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'appname.My.MyProject' and 'AppName.My.MyProject'.
```

The program is apparently taking my application and flat-out *inventing* a lower-case version of its namespace. I've searched the code with Match Case on, and there's no Project, Module, Class, String or even variable name with the lower-case "appname".

I've tried explicitly referencing "AppName.My.Application.Info.ProductName", and it's still shown as being ambiguous. I've tried referencing "[AppName].My.Application.Info.ProductName" with the same result.

Annoyingly, even though this reference can't be resolved, the code carries on happily, and resolves to "appname.My.Application.Info.ProductName" which, "appname" not existing, returns an empty string instead of the information stored in AppName's My.Application.Info section.

Does anyone know where this phantom lowercase namespace is coming from and how I can get rid of it so that my code can actually do what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: Is AppName a common name that might be used by some framework components? If so, does the error continue if you rename with an odd suffix (e.g. AppName_XyZ22_13)?

Comment: VB.NET is case-insensitive. `AppName` and `appname` are the same identifier. It's not inventing anything at all. Your problem doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't *think* it was a common name, but that did fix it. Feel free to submit an answer for points. I am dumbfounded that this has solved the problem.

Comment: @Cody I'm aware of the case insensitivity. The problem, I assume, arises from the fact that there is both an "appname" and an "AppName" namespace. Why it's picking the lower-case namespace over the upper-case namespace is anyone's guess.

Comment: @Frosty: So your application is seriously named `AppName`? I thought that was just an example. Considered something a little more descriptive?

Comment: @Cody No, it's not actually called AppName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AppName is a common name that might be used by some framework components, you might want to change the name to something else and see if the error disappears.

E.g. rename AppName to AppName_XyZ22_13.